# How to remove uninstalls from Installation class?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am migrating my app out of Parse to mlab. Currently, I have millions of rows in the Installation class, however the vast majority of these are no longer valid due to uninstallations. Migrating these rows is unnecessary and expensive.

I would like to know how I can delete Installation rows that are no longer valid. Is there a way to do this in bulk?

Also, are there any side effects of perhaps dropping ALL rows in this table? What is the Installation object being used for, besides push? Because my app registers for Installation at every launch, only users who are still actively using the app will re-create the Installation row. And also, how can I do this in bulk?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you able to know which Installation objects are valid or invalid? An uninstallation doesn't remove anything from Parse

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering the same.

Comment: Then you should have made a feature of your app that frequently updated some "last_accessed" value for your installations.

Answer (score 0):

As cricket_007 has posted, we cannot identify uninstalls. But we can determine old installs based on `app_version_code` column in Installation class.